# When I use CMake to compile a program to catch an exception, a compile error occurs. Anyone can help me?

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-errors

When I use CMake to compile my program. I faced with this error.

```
framework/base.h:146:30: 错误：expected unqualified-id before ‘&’ token
         catch(std::bad_typeid& e)
```

my program is posted up as followed:

```
 void Do()
    {        bool ret = false;
        try
        {
            ret = run();
        }
        catch(std::bad_typeid& e)
        {
            std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
            errMsg = e.what();
            ret = false;
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            std::cerr << "unknown error" << '\n';
            errMsg = "unknown error";
            ret = false;
        }
    }
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
include_directories(../common)
```

because this function defines in a Header file. some other modules include this file to use the function do().
So I just write a `include_directories()` statement in `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add the CMake code to your question post *as text*. Also, please do not post *images* of code; rather, add your source code (and **full** error message) to your question post **as text**. Consider reading through the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of the site.

Comment: virtual void Do()
    {        bool ret = false;
        try
        {
            ret = run();
        }
        catch(std::bad_typeid& e)
        {
            std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
            errMsg = e.what();
            ret = false;
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            std::cerr << "unknown error" << '\n';
            errMsg = "unknown error";
            ret = false;
        }
    }

Comment: Did you `#include <`[`typeinfo`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/bad_typeid)`>`?

Comment: this is a part of my function, which runs ok in windows, but failed in Linux.

Comment: i have included this <typeinfo> I try it serveral minutes ago. but still failed.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i include the header file by include file <new>
finally, it works.